# Is it okay to use the same pw for root and secure boot?

Tags: 22.04, password, security, secure-boot

If I install with secure boot enabled I’m asked to set a pw which I’m told I won’t need often. Is it safe to use the same pw as for root?

Comment: No. In Ubuntu, enabling the `root` userid is discouraged for security reasons. Use `sudo` instead. Read `man sudo sudoers`. Passwords in Ubuntu's `/etc/passwd` are not related to Secure Boot passwords.

Comment: I mean the sudo pw. Isn't it the same as the root pw? I think this is significant because anyone with secure boot enabled will be asked to set 2 pws during install. Lot's of people will use the same pw twice.

Comment: @H3R3T1K no root has an encrypted password that is not known. And using 2 passwords the same is not a security risk -for Ubuntu-. It is a users choice making your question a matter of opinion ;) Security should never hinder a user and a user should not be hindered by a lack of security. The middleground is where Ubuntu lives.

Comment: Note that unless you encrypt your partitions, anyone with physical access to your computer can in principle do anything even without the root password.

Answer (score 1):

You will increase safety choosing different and strong passwords.